# To find optical flow value using matlab

Tags: matlab, opticalflow

how do you find the value of optical flow (vertical and horizontal component) from the the actual displacement which around (5.232-5,342i)  the screen shot are in the comments
i need help with the coding hopefully

Comment: Can you post the code and the images you used to get that data?  Why is your displacement imaginary?  Is the imaginary component the vertical displacement?

Comment: can you find out from the code because the result file is pretty huge and dont use the input as yuv use those image is sent . Thanks

Comment: I'm having difficulty getting the code.  Can you not simply modify your post?

Comment: sure and thanks a all lots for doing this u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have calculated the Horizontal and Vertical Components, we have a real and an imaginary value (a+bi):

`velocityHx(i) = real(OpticalFlow{i,1});
     velocityVy(i) = imag(OpticalFlow{i,1});`

If you want the magnitude of the value of the OpticalFlow, you just need to calculate the absolute value, just like in Mathematics:

`velocityMagnitudeCentroide(i) = velocityHx(i)*velocityHx(i) + velocityVy(i)*velocityVy(i);`